# Swing Toolbar placement

Tags: java, swing, toolbar

I want to display a JToolbar within right side of a split pane, which is also going to contain a JTabbedPane, how can we do that ? wrap TabbedPane and toolbar in some component? ps: user should not be able to minimize, etc in right side pane...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a JPanel on the right side of the split pane.

Give the JPanel a BorderLayout.

Add the JToolbar to the NORTH of the JPanel, and the JTabbedPane to the CENTER.